# Apex iframe condtion

Tags: visualforce, iframe

I have a Visual force page which has no dependency of apex class.

I had a formula field called user object label as Business and Api name as Business__c.I need to add condition based on log in user

If login user has two different business sales and Marketing.

**My Previous code**:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">
<apex:iframe src="Link1"
height="1110px" width="1900px" scrolling="true"/>  

</apex:page>
```

**My new code wants to be**:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">
if(loginuser.Business__c == "sales")
    <apex:iframe src="Link1"
    height="1110px" width="1900px" scrolling="true"/> 
if(loginuser.Business__c == "Marketing")
 <apex:iframe src="Link2"
    height="1110px" width="1900px" scrolling="true"/>   
    </apex:page>
```

could you please anyone help me how to add condition in vf page without dependency of apex class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CASE statement to dynamically select a link:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">
  <apex:iframe src="{!CASE(
     $User.Business__c, 
     'Sales', 'URL1',
     'Marketing', 'URL2',
     null)}" 
     height="1110px" 
     width="1900px" 
     scrolling="true"/> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank you so Much sfdcfox , I have another doubt  Url1 is using two buisness sales and test

Comment: A case statement is already a selection of OR values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "rendered" attribute of Iframe.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">
  <apex:iframe src="Link1"
height="1110px" width="1900px" rendered = "{!$User.Business__c == 'sales'}" scrolling="true"/> 
  <apex:iframe src="Link2" rendered = "{!$User.Business__c == 'Marketing'}"
height="1110px" width="1900px" scrolling="true"/>   
</apex:page>
```

I have updated your code try this.

Comment: Please don't ask for someone to accept your answer unless they indicate that the answer solved their problem. Read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109776/300295) or more information. You'll get your checkmarks and upvotes simply by providing good answers.